# Asp net core routing multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to route asp.net core application.

I have having this scenario:

```
[Route("/{user}")]
public IActionResult FirstAction(string user)
{
    // Code
}

[Route("/{user}/{project}")]
public IActionResult SecondAction(string user, string project)
{
    // Code 2
}
```

Problem i am having is that when user goes to link `/something` it fires both methods (`// Code 1` and `// Code 2`) but i want only first one to fire.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Umm, it shouldn't be possible for 2 actions to run? Could you look at the actual request URL within the action through e.g. `HttpContext.Request`?

Comment: let the first slash away

Comment: I do not want multiple actions, i just want multiple parameters to be passed without using `?user=`. Same behavior as on `github.com/{organization}/{project}`

Comment: That's why my answer. The ?user is replaced with the rest path /users

Answer (score 1):

Use a better REST API routing

```
[Route("/users/{user}")]

[Route("/users/{user}/projects/{project}")]
```

Comment: I want same behavior as on `github.com/{organization}/{project}`

Comment: Is that also the API route? Or you are taking about the one in the browser? Because the one in the browser is managed in another place

Comment: It is browser route

Comment: But your question is about an API route? In that case they are different. And you can maintain a different routing convention from what the user sees and what happens with a backend server... The browser route can be manipulated in many different ways. But for the API I keep my suggestion of the answer I provided

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that both actions are fired? Which version of ASP NET Core are you using?

I tested the following:

```
    [HttpGet("/{user}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Test1(string user)
    {
        return "User " + user;
    }

    [HttpGet("/{user}/{project}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Test2(string user, string project)
    {
        return "User " + user + " Project " + project;
    }
```

The routes where explicit. If there was only one string Test1 was routed. If there were two strings Test2 was routed.

---

Furthermore, please note the following: If you put a leading / into the route any prefixes will be ignored.